# Variation on Stokes Theorem for Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, closed-form

Let $n >1$ and $\omega \in \Omega^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})$ such that $d\omega = 0$. Is the following statement true:

For any compact, oriented, $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$, we have $\displaystyle \int\limits_{M}j^*\omega = 0$ with $j:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ the inclusion map.

This calls for the Theorem of Stokes ( I thought to apply it two times), but $M$ isn't necessarily a boundary of another Manifold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^n$, and so in particular the $(n-1)$-st cohomology group 
$$
   H^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace) = H^{n-1}(\mathbb{S}^n)
$$
vanishes. In particular, your closed form $\omega$ is exact; that is, there is an $(n-2)$-form $\eta$ with $d\eta = \omega$. You can now use Stokes' theorem in the usual way, together with the fact that $\partial M = \emptyset$, to show that your integral is $0$.

Comment: I can agree with your proof, but the statement ' $\partial M = \emptyset$' seems a bit odd. $M$ is compact, but this doesn't necessarily mean that it has no boundary?

Comment: You'll need the assumption $\partial M = \emptyset$. For instance let $\partial_r$ be the gradient vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the distance from the origin function, which I'll call $r$, similar to the field $X$ in [Xipan's](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/78637/xipan-xiao) answer. $\partial_r$ corresponds to an exact one-form. But taking the line integral of $\partial_r$ over a path (this path is $M$) from $a$ to $b$ gives $r(b) - r(a)$ -- because $M$ has boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Consider n=2 and let $X=(x,y,z)/r^3$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, $X$ is a vector field defined on $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$. It's easy to compute 
$$\operatorname{div}(X)=\sum\frac{1\cdot r^3-x\cdot3r^2\cdot r_x}{r^6}$$
$$=\sum\frac{r^3-x\cdot 3r^2 (x/r)}{r^6}$$
$$=\sum\frac{r^3-3rx^2}{r^6}$$
$$=\frac{3r^3}{r^6}-\frac{3r}{r^6}\sum x^2$$
$$=3/r^3-3/r^3=0$$
So let $\Omega=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ and $\omega=i(X)\Omega$ we have $d\omega=\operatorname{div}(X)\Omega=0$ but $\int_{S^2}j^*\omega=4\pi$

Comment: For $n = 2$, isn't the OP given a closed $1$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbf{R}^{3} \setminus\{0\}$, and is asking whether the integral of $\omega$ over an arbitrary closed _curve_ vanishes...?

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that he was asking for n-1 surfaces. Then yes the selected answer is correct.